How to read Secrets from the Kubernetes and use in the angular application enviroment.ts file
How to read Secrets from the Kubernetes and use in the angular application enviroment.ts file.
In Angular application, I have a environment.ts file to configure the "Clientsecrets" for Oauth, instead using this Clientsecrets value directly from this environment.ts, we need to read from Kubernetes secrets under Storage (we use to see it from Rancher).
I tried this,
mySecret: process.env.MY_SECRET but not works. this "MY_SECRET" throwing error

process.env is only available server-side in Node. You'd need to use server-side code to pass this value to Angular.

Is there any other way to read in the angular application itself without using server-side code.  like while deploying to Kubernetes, I would like to replace the Client_ID value  client_id: "$Client_ID" with the Secret value from the Kubernetes Secrets.

You would either have to do that as some type of scripting in the deployment or in server-side code. I'm not familiar with Kubernetes, so I'm not sure what's possible.

Looking at the [docs]https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-config-file/) and sample here you can use the secrets and configmap you have as env variable of a workload:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-auth
  namespace: app1
type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
stringData:
  username: admin
  password: admin
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-config
  namespace: app1
data:
  server.host: "10.10.10.245"
  server.port: "3660"
  db.name: web-application
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web-app
  labels:
    app: web-app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ubuntu-app
      image: ubuntu:latest
      command: ["/bin/sleep", "3650d"]
      ## Setup the volumeMounts
      volumeMounts:
      ## ConfigMap Mount
      - name: db-config
        mountPath: /etc/config
      ## Secret Mount
      - name: db-auth
        mountPath: /etc/authentication
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "250Mi"
          cpu: "0.5"
          limits:
          memory: "1024Mi"
          cpu: "1"
  volumes:
    - name: db-config
      configMap:
        name: db-config
    - name: db-auth
      secret:
        secretName: db-auth
  restartPolicy: Always

You can look at this article for more example on using key reference from the secrets
